# Is it possible to interpret some Martin-Löf types as abelian monoids in such a way that any abelian monoid can be represented as a type?

Tags: type-theory, dependent-types, group-theory

For instance, I can interpret the unit type as the trivial monoid with one element. Non-dependent pairs $A \times B$ can be interpreted as the direct sum $A ⊕ B$ when $A$ and $B$ can both be interpreted as abelian monoids. For the sum type $A + B$, you can define the monoid operation as:
$$inj_L(a_0) \cdot inj_L(a_1) = inj_L(a_0 \cdot a_1)$$
$$inj_L(a) \cdot inj_R(b) = inj_R(b)$$
$$inj_R(b) \cdot inj_L(a) = inj_R(b)$$
$$inj_R(b_0) \cdot inj_R(b_1) = inj_R(b_0 \cdot b_1)$$
(Although this does mean that the interpretations of $A+B$ and $B+A$ are different).

So far though this scheme only lets me represent finite monoids where $\forall x: G, x \cdot x = x$. I'd like a way to extend it to infinite and more interesting monoids. That will at least require a way to interpret W-types but I can't see what that interpretation could be. Does such an interpretation exist? Or is there a simple proof that what I'm trying to do is impossible?

Comment: Martin-Löf type theory proves that $A + B$ and $B + A$ are isomorphic types, so your solution for giving the monoid structure to a sum can't work.

Comment: Are you asking whether Martin-Löf type theory has an intepretation in the category of abelian monoids and monoid homomorphisms?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Since the syntax of Martin-Löf type theory has only countably many types, but there is a proper class of non-isomorphic (abelian) monoids, the question in your title obviously has a negative answer, as stated. Furthermore, even if you say something like "I am only interested in finite monoids", you still have to explain how *homomorphisms* of monoids and monoid constructions are supposed to interact with type theory. Otherwise, I can just assign arbitrary monoid structures to the finite types, while making sure that I've covered all isomoprhism classes.

Comment: And then, at the end of the day, the answer will still be negative, because the category of abelian monoids has a zero object (the trivial monoid is both initial and terminal) but in type theory the empty and the unit type are distinct.

Comment: I'm not trying to define a functor from types to monoids. I just want a way to map (some) types to monoids such that, for any type, I can syntactically check if it has a corresponding monoid and what that monoid is, and that for any monoid (or at least any monoid that I could define as a type and an operation in ML type theory - I think that addresses your infinities concern?) there is some type which maps to that monoid.

Comment: You did not address any issue. Again: there are countably many types and a proper class of monoids. And also: suppose you're interested in some countable collection of monoids where $M_{k,i}$ is the $i$-th monoid with $k$ elements. Enumerate types so that $T_{k,i}$ is the $i$-th type with $k$ closed terms. Assign monoid structure $M_{k,i}$ to $T_{k,i}$ via some bijection of the carriers. This accomplishes what you asked for (or something like it). Please explain how much strcuture you want to preserve, otherwise we can come up with totally arbitrary assignments.

Comment: How can there be countably many types but a proper class of $\sum (T: Type) \sum (i: T) \sum ((\cdot): (T \times T) \to T))\prod (a b c: T)((a \cdot i = a) \times (i \cdot a = a) \times ((a \cdot b) \cdot c = a \cdot (b \cdot c)))$? A totally arbitrary assignment sounds fine so long as there's a straightforward way to translate back-and-forth (eg. the translation can be encoded as a handful of rules, not some infinitely-long lookup table) and it gives me a way to pun infinite commutative monoids like $(Nat, +, 0)$ as a type. Can you give an example of such an assignment?

Comment: @AndrewCann How I would start formalizing what (it sounds like) you're asking, at least originally, is: given a (set-theoretic) monoid, can I map that monoid to a type in such a way that when interpreted (preferably in some natural way), the interpretation would be the original monoid I started with, or at least an isomorphic monoid? With a reading like this, Andrej Bauer's concerns about set-theoretic sizes are pretty apparent. How is what you intend different from this reading of the question?

Comment: I've only been thinking in terms of types, not sets. For my purposes a "monoid" refers to that big type I gave in my previous comment. I want to extend ML type theory by giving some types a monoidal operation such that there's an injection from that big type down to $Type$ (where the injection preserves the operation).

Comment: For context: I'm designing a type theory and I noticed that the $?T$ modality
from linear logic can be used to represent any number of values of type $T$
being produced concurrently. So if I can equip some $T$ with a commutative monoidal structure
then I can add a primitive $threadJoin : ?T \to T$ operation to my type theory. But for this to be useful I'd like a way to take any commutative monoid $M$ - defined within my type theory - and show that it's isomorphic to some $T$ which is naturally equipped with a commutative monoidal structure according my type theory.

Comment: I don't see how that's necessary nor sufficient to make `threadJoin` useful. Either $T$ is fixed, in which case you can either prove or assert that it has the structure of a (commutative) monoid, or $T$ is arbitrary, in which case the most natural thing would be to pass in a proof to `threadJoin` that $T$ is a monoid. A third alternative is $T$ is arbitrary, but we restrict the introduction rules of $?$ to only allow types with a monoid structure. None of this requires every monoid to be "representable" as a type in some manner. (Also, I'd suspect users would care *which* monoid gets used.)

Comment: Aha, you should have given context right away, instead of asking a strange question.

Comment: For any given usage of `threadJoin` I can check whether $T$ is monoidal and reject the program if it's not. I'm not sure that passing a proof to `threadJoin` would be the most natural thing, since that would add a huge, ugly axiom to my theory. I'd rather provide a library function that takes a monoid definition and converts it to some contrived, ugly type which comes naturally equipped with that monoidal structure.

Comment: eg. According to the rules I gave originally, if I define $Bool = 1 + 1, false = inj_L(*), true = inj_R(*)$ then $Bool$ is naturally equipped with the $(Bool, \lor false)$ monoid structure. But I could have some library-defined type of monoids, define the $(Bool, \land, true)$ monoid using it, then use this monoid with `threadJoin` via a library function that puns $Bool$ as $Bool$ using the $not$ function.

Comment: After having seen the comments, I am voting to close the question because it is not at all clear what you are asking. The question asks for one thing (namely how to equip *every* type in Martin-Löf type theory with a monoid structure) but the comments want another thing (namely how to give a subuniverse of "monoidal types"). The advice given by @DerekElkins is good and should be taken to heart.

Comment: The question title specifically says "some" types, and the question itself says that I need "at least" a way to interpret W-types. The word "every" is never used.

I'm sorry I wasn't more clear though, and thank you both for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately you gave us some context in the comments (always a good idea to include it in your question). Rather than doing what you're trying to do, I believe [quantitative type theory](https://bentnib.org/quantitative-type-theory.pdf) is what you're looking for.

Comment: QTT is my starting point. I'm basically trying to turn it into a process calculus with an in-built notion of commutativity.

Comment: Do you want every type to have an intrinsic structure of an abelian monoid? The empty type might pose a problem, what will its unit be?

Comment: The empty type does have a commutative binary operation, just with no identity. My rule for $A+B$ would actually only require $B$ to satisfy that weaker condition. I don't need every type to have the structure of an abelian monoid, just for enough of them to that any abelian monoid is isomorphic to some type (sans infinities concerns).

Comment: Ugh, I totally missed the word "some" in the title. Maybe emphasize that bit a little more.

Comment: Sorry, I'm guessing my using the words "interpret" and "represented" led to confusion by making it sound like I was talking about model theory or something (?). Also it wasn't really a good question since it's far too specific to my niche problem. Thanks though.